# How to loop over comparison of two model lists with anova()

Tags: r, loops, anova

I'm a rookie in R Studio and don't know how to make a reproducible example of this, but I hope you get the hang of it:

I have two lists, `model1_list` and `model2_list` that both include 47 model outputs for ERGMs. I want to compare each model with their counterpart model in the other list like this

```
anova(model1_list[[1]], model2_list[[1]])
```

However, I cannot come up with a solution to loop all of the `anova()` tests at once. I've tried

```
anova_m1_m2 <- list
for(i in c(1:47)){
  m1 <- model1_list[[i]]
  m2 <- model2_list[[i]]
  a_m1_m2 <- anova(m1, m2)
  anova_m1_m2[[(i)]] <- a_m1_m2
}
```

But get the error message
`Error in anova_m1_m2[[(i)]] <- a_m1_m2 :  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it to `anova_m1_m2 <- list()`, or better:

```
vector(mode = "list", length = length(model1_list))
```

Or simply do

```
anova_m1_m2 <- Map(anova, model1_list, model2_list)
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks for the more elegant suggestions as well!